# Why/how am I able to exceed the configured length of a varchar in MySQL? [my mistake, I can't]

Tags: mysql, varchar, mysql-5.7

[Edit: my mistake, read the wrong column for the type, the one I'm inserting into is LONGTEXT, not varchar(190)]
I am working with an application that stores the majority of its information in a MySQL database (MySQL server 5.7). One particular value I'm looking at has a 255 character limit enforced by the GUI but, when I looked at that column in the table where it's stored, it's set to varchar(190). I confirmed that I can enter 255-character values in the GUI and that they are not truncated, as I expected.

How can a varchar(190) column store >190 characters? Are there any consequences to doing it this way?

I read [11.4.1 The CHAR and VARCHAR Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html) and it states that anything over the limit should be truncated.

Comment: Some characters uses more than one byte to be stored. Varchar limit is 255 bytes, not 255 characters. That's why you can do this.

Comment: But, varchar(190) = a string limit of 190 characters. If it were bytes and some of my characters were taking up >1 byte, that would be a further increase beyond the expected limit.

Comment: I think Elias is correct.  You have a varchar(190), but what is the character encoding?  If your database, table or column is one of the UTF, ot possibly other, character encodings then indeed, not all "characters" take up the same space.

Comment: The character set is utf8mb4 which, as I understand it, means that a character can take anywhere between 1 & 4 bytes. Unless I'm seriously confused (a possibility), the x in varchar(x) indicates the number of characters. So, varchar(190) would take anywhere between 190+1 and (190x4)+1 bytes to store (the +1 = varchar overhead).

Comment: VARCHAR's limit is per character, not per byte. If you have latin1 for one VARCHAR(N) column and utf8 for another, you can store N single-bytes characters in first one and N multi-bytes characters in the second. I do not know how you added it into you column, I got error on my 5.7 that is in strict mode.

Comment: + Even if varchar(190) was 190 bytes, I don't see how I could be storing 255 characters, unless they were taking >1 byte each, which I don't think is possible.

Comment: Was the table created in 5.7 or on early version and then server was upgraded? Previously it used to be per byte (I do not remember the exact version they changed it). Also, what is your server mode? Can you try to create a new test table with VARCHAR(5) and try to insert 6 characters there right now?

Comment: I don't know as much about the modes, but I believe the mode is STRICT_TRANS_TABLES (I executed "SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;" in Workbench.

Comment: The table was created in 5.7. Everything is automatically populated the first time the application is run with an empty schema. I'll try inserting my >190 string into the table in Workbench and then also try creating a new test table with varchar(5).

Comment: One more idea: what is that 255 characters value? Could it be escaped by GUI so it looks like 255 characters in GUI but in fact it is still under SQL limit? You should double check the value using mysql client + check LENGTH(col)

Comment: Ok, I feel silly. I was able to insert 230 characters, so I went back to the table info. I had shifted the columns by one. The one I'm inserting into is LONGTEXT!!! I'll edit my original question with my error and answer myself. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that I can't.

Misread the column types because that column is `varchar(255)` when the application builds the schema in PostgreSQL. It's `LONGTEXT`* in MySQL, which explains why I was able to get past the 190 characters. I tried inserting my 230 char test string into the `varchar(190)` column and it throws an error, as expected.

Need more coffee.

* *Not sure why `LONGTEXT`, when the application GUI limits input to 255 characters, but I'll need to ask the people who built it.*